# scrapy shell does not show >>> on adding second spider

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Just started working on a scrapy project. I created a new scrapy project using the following command:

```
scrapy startproject <projectname>
```

Inside the spiders folder, I am creating my scrapy class which has all the logic for scraping the data. I am using Scrapy Shell for testing.

When I create the first spider, scrapy shell is working fine. But on creating the second spider, the scrapy shell is not working. Using the below command to invoke the scrapy shell:

```
scrapy shell <url>
```

I am seeing the following:

```
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   fetch(url[, redirect=True]) Fetch URL and update local objects (by default, redirects 
are followed)
[s]   fetch(req)                  Fetch a scrapy.Request and update local objects 
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

I am expecting the following:

```
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   fetch(url[, redirect=True]) Fetch URL and update local objects (by default, redirects 
are followed)
[s]   fetch(req)                  Fetch a scrapy.Request and update local objects 
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
 >>>
```

The >>> is missing in the last line. Is there any config that needs to be added for this?

Comment: you are in the wrong fodler, you need to go out of the scrapy project folder and open cmd prompt there

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are starting a scrapy shell from within a scrapy shell. By running `scrapy shell <url>` you are actually not testing your code, you are only starting an interactive shell where you can for example test XPath or CSS expressions ([see Scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)).

I guess what you are actually trying to do is to test and run your spiders ([see Scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#how-to-run-our-spider)). So lets say for example you created two spiders named 'spider1.py' and 'spider2.py' inside of your spiders-folder. In spider1.py you assigned your spider a name of `name = 'foo'`. In spider2.py you assigned your spider a name of `name = 'bar'`. Now to run those spiders you can call `scrapy crawl foo` and likewise `scrapy crawl bar`.